# Как я могу избавиться от ошибки 'no changelog could be found', связанной с Liquibase, не используя Liquibase?

Tags: java, liquibase

Работаю над [проектом](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/pom.xml#L44), используя `POM` со следующими зависимостями:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jooq -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

во время запуска текущей версии проекта, я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.
```

Изучив различные ответы на англоязычном `Stackoverflow`:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63227085/8370915
2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68883660/8370915
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810712/8370915

пришёл к выводу, что для того, чтобы её решить нужно добавлять дополнительные файлы по типу `db.changelog-master.yaml`:

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml does not exist
```

В связи с этим у меня вопрос, могу ли я убрать эту ошибку, не используя, в принципе, `Liquibase` как инструмент?

Если да, то каким образом я могу это сделать?

Спрашиваю это, потому что в случае удаления зависимости `liquibase-core`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

У меня возникает другая ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException
```

которую получается решить только добавлением [зависимости](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164476/8370915) `Liquibase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено:

Как одно из решений, это добавить `changelog` файл:

```
db.changelog-master.yaml
```

в директории `resource/db/changelog/` со следующим содержанием:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: invzbl3

name: db.changelog-master.yaml
environment: testing
is-enabled: false
```

используя `is-enabled` со значением `false`.